# include uncertainties of known parameters of function to fit using curve_fit in python

Tags: python

I am using uncertainty package within the Python. I have a function like A*x+N
where N is a fixed parameter with uncertainty say N=1.0+/-0.1. I would like to get the parameter A by fitting the equation to data set y with errors yerr.

I have attempted using @uncertainties.wrap but not success.

```
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y=np.array([2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6])
yerr=np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
N=unumpy.uarray([1.0],[0.1])
def fitfun(x,A,N):
    return A*x+N

A,cov=curve_fit(uncertainties.wrap(fitfun)(x,A,N),x,y,sigma=yerr, absolute_sigma=True)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.