# Incorporating uncertainty of pre-determined parameter into curve_fit operation

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting, uncertainty

I have a model like y=A*x+N where N is a fixed parameter with uncertainty say N=1.0+/-0.1. I would like to curve fit this model to a data set in order to determine A but with an uncertainty value (calculated based on the uncertainty in the fixed parameter N). I have been doing curve fits with curve_fit in Python.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287252/include-uncertainties-of-known-parameters-of-function-to-fit-using-curve-fit-in) which was asked a couple of years ago but hasn't gotten any answers, so this is a sort of bump.

Comment: Are you interested in bounds, such as limiting N to be between 0.9 and 1.1? The curve_fit routine accepts bounds, and the docs states for the "bounds" parameter as: "Lower and upper bounds on parameters. Defaults to no bounds. Each element of the tuple must be either an array with the length equal to the number of parameters, or a scalar (in which case the bound is taken to be the same for all parameters.) Use np.inf with an appropriate sign to disable bounds on all or some parameters."

Comment: If `N=1` is the optimum value you don't have to do anything. The error in `N` only plays a role if you calculate the error of the final prediction.

Comment: @mikuszefski I am calculating the error of the final prediction, and the error in N plays a role.

Comment: sure it does, but not for fitting `A`

Comment: @mikuszefski I am aware.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if you use bounds, generally speaking the initial parameter estimates should be within those bounds. Since the default initial parameter estimates for scipy's curve_fit are all 1.0 by default, and this can be an important detail when using bounds.

Comment: So?...Fit with `N=1` and use the according errors of `A` and `N`, when determining the error of `y`.